# how to force page breaks?

Tags: java, reporting, birt

I have a table, grouped by an element, like this :

```
[GroupingELT]  
Header1  |  Header2  
[ELT1]   |  [ELT2]
```

And i'd like to have the [GroupingELT] alone in the center of a page, the table on the next page and so on. Could you help me with that ?

I'm new to birt (started today :p) so don't hesitate to redirect me to the appropriate tutorial if the answer should be obvious.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a header row for the group in question in the table object, you need to insert one.

Then, select the header row in the layout, open the property editor, select Page Break from the list of properties and change both Before and After from auto to always.

Comment: What happened? Did you remember to put any data items in the header row?

Comment: in Table Groupe > Header > row 1 before and after page break are set to always, and row 2 before is set to always, after to auto.
The before row 1 seems to work, but not the after..

Comment: What did the output look like? Do you have more than one group in the table, or was row 2 a second header row for group 1? Did you have any data items in row 1?